# Embed-able HTML snipet in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe, bitnami

I have a CMS in wordpress. I want a HTML snippet which we'll use it to show some content in other website.

Main CMS site is http://example.com, other site is http://other.example.com.

Now we want footer to be same, i.e. abc.com and other.abc.com should share the footer. So that If I change footer from CMS, I don't need to change that in main site. The main site will use `iframe` to show the footer.

*What I did*
I created a static file and put in the folder (I am serving CMS through apache-bitnami tomcat stack) so the footer URL became http://example.com/footer/footer.html.

Issue is it is not allowing me to access via iFrame because of X-FRAME-OPTION is set to SAMEORIGIN. I don't want this to be changed for all the website.

Is there any plugin which creates embedded-able HTML snippet? Is there other way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The iFrame makes **the user** read from http://example.com/footer/footer.html, but due to security constraints he doesn't do that and nothing is displayed.

So **you** (aka the server) has to grab the code from http://example.com/footer/footer.html and send it to the user.

Basically you create have to (somehow) create a site http://other.example.com/footer/footer.php (or any other url) which is no static file but **mirrors the content** of http://example.com/footer/footer. Then you make an iFrame to http://other.example.com/footer/footer.php (the mirror) and the users loads from the mirror, the mirror loads from http://example.com/footer/footer and the footer is displayed.

This is my programmer solution, i don't know how much of a (non-) programmer you are and if you want to do this.